# Can I update my Redmi 5 beta to Stable manually?

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, android-versions, xiaomi, redmi

Can I update my Redmi 5 beta to Stable manually by going to 
About phone > system update > choose update packages.
N select the stable zip file n flash.
Can I do that ?

Comment: Definitely. You can install zip file from your updater from settings. I tried switching from chinese to global, beta to stable on my Redmi 1s several times. Keep in mind that device get into factory while switching. Backup recommended before any operations.

Comment: @RahulGopi Okk. Thank you.  Device get into factory. Means my data will be erased ?

Comment: If you're installing stable zip over beta version, then your data will be erased. Also, the same for switching from chinese to global. If you're trying  stable zip over stable zip, then there's no data loss.

Comment: @RahulGopi Okk Thanks

Comment: Should I download Fastboot ROM or Recovery ROM ????

Comment: If you download recovery rom, you can install it from updater app in miui, for faatboot, you need to go-to faatboot mode and install